# xslt grouping using Munchian with multiple elements in key

Tags: xslt

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <contact>
      <forename>John</forename>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
      <charge>1</charge>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <forename>John</forename>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
      <charge>2</charge>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <forename>John</forename>
      <surname>Jones</surname>
      <charge>3</charge>
    </contact>
</root>
```

Desired output (group charges by forename, surname):

```
<root>
  <Person>
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Jones</Last>
    <Charges>
        <Charge>3</Charge>
    </Charges>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Smith</Last>
    <Charges>
       <Charge>1</Charge>
       <Charge>2</Charge>
    </Charges>
  </Person>
</root>
```

The XSL (adapting the Munchian method described here [Munchian Method](http://jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for multiple elements in the key (forename, surname):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="contacts-by-name" match="contact" use="concat(forename, surname)" />
<xsl:template match="records">
 <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-name', concat(forename, surname))[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:sort select="concat(forename, surname)" />
      <Person>
        <First><xsl:value-of select="forename"/></First>
        <Last><xsl:value-of select="surname"/></Last>
        <Charges>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('contacts-by-name', concat(forename, surname))">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Charge"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Charges>
      </Person>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual output (notice the charges are empty):

```
<root>
  <Person>
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Jones</Last>
    <Charges/>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Smith</Last>
    <Charges/>
  </Person>
</root>
```

Comment: Found had a typo... select="Charge" instead of select="charge". Works now.

Comment: A word of warning, although it probably doesn't apply in this case, if you had all lower-case names, then a person with the name "jo earnie" would share the same key as a person with the name "joe arnie". Therefore, you often see a 'delimiting' character being used in the concat statement. For example `concat(firstname, '|', lastname)`.

Comment: Indeed. That's actually what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Found had a typo... select="Charge" instead of select="charge". Works now.